# Slather Xcode test specific Group

Tags: xcode, code-coverage, slather

I need the code coverage for a specific Group(Folder) in my Xcode project with slather.

Already tried config file .slather.yml with property ignore. The generated html has files listed in third libraries (Swift PM). I am just interested in a specific Group.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just add this to your .slather.yml file.

ignore:

- ../*